# CupertinoDatePicker resets the hours and minutes when changing month and year

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a CupertinoDatePicker with the initial DateTime as `DateTime.now()`. However, when I change the month or year, the hours/minutes gets reset to 0:00.

[The time is initially set to 17:37](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTJMZ.png)

[However if I change the month/year, the time resets to 0:00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwQKT.png)

My code so far:

```
class EventsCreate extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventsCreate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EventsCreateState createState() => _EventsCreateState();
}

class _EventsCreateState extends State<EventsCreate> {
  DateTime dateTimeStart = DateTime.now();
  DateTime dateTimeEnd = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: 24));

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    ...
    Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Starts',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 109.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                  '${DateFormat.MMMM().format(dateTimeStart).substring(0, 3)} ${dateTimeStart.day}, ${dateTimeStart.year}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue)
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              showCupertinoModalPopup(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
                                      height: 250,
                                      child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        initialDateTime: dateTimeStart,
                                        onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newTime) {
                                          setState(() => dateTimeStart = newTime);
                                        },
                                        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                                      )
                                  )
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                  DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dateTimeStart),
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue)
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              showCupertinoModalPopup(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
                                      height: 250,
                                      child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        use24hFormat: true,
                                        initialDateTime: dateTimeStart,
                                        onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newTime) {
                                          setState(() => dateTimeStart = newTime);
                                        },
                                        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
                                      )
                                  )
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                      height: 1.5,
                      color: const Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Ends',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 116.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                  '${DateFormat.MMMM().format(dateTimeEnd).substring(0, 3)} ${dateTimeEnd.day}, ${dateTimeEnd.year}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue)
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              showCupertinoModalPopup(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
                                      height: 250,
                                      child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        initialDateTime: dateTimeEnd,
                                        onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newTime) {
                                          setState(() => dateTimeEnd = newTime);
                                        },
                                        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                                      )
                                  )
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: const Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                  DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dateTimeEnd),
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue)
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              showCupertinoModalPopup(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
                                      height: 250,
                                      child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        use24hFormat: true,
                                        initialDateTime: dateTimeEnd,
                                        onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newTime) {
                                          setState(() => dateTimeEnd = newTime);
                                        },
                                        mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
                                      )
                                  )
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )
            ),
```

Comment: Your code contains lots of irrelevant parts. Could you boil It down to a minimal example?

Comment: Yes sorry about that. I've boiled the code down to the relevant parts. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized your `CupertinoDatePicker` with the mode `CupertinoDatePickerMode.date`. This will create the UI as desired by you, but also has the sideeffect that any date you select is set to midnight per default.

These are the relevant lines in your code:

```dart
onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newTime) {
    setState(() => dateTimeEnd = newTime);
},
mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
```

In the beginning, you use

```
DateTime dateTimeStart = DateTime.now();
DateTime dateTimeEnd = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(hours: 24));
```

which also contains the current hours and minute. So everything shows up as correct.

So you might want to change your code to

```dart
onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newTime) {
    var oldHour = dateTimeEnd.hour;
    var oldMinute = dateTimeEnd.minute;
    var newDay = newTime.day;
    var newMonth = newTime.month;
    var newYear = newTime.year;

    var adjustedDate = DateTime(newYear, newMonth, newDay, oldHour, oldMinute);
    setState(() => dateTimeEnd = adjustedDate);
},
mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
```

Similar correction could be performed for `dateTimeStart`/`dateTimeEnd`.
More info in the [docs to DateTime](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) and [CupertinoDatePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker/CupertinoDatePicker.html).

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you! I figured CupertinoDatePickerMode.date would preserve the original time so I originally thought this was a bug with my UI. Good to know!